# Intel code coverage -> undefined reference to `std::string::_S_compare(unsigned long, unsigned long)

Tags: compare, code-coverage, intel, libstdc++

I compile code under Redhat 6 using the intel compiler icc/icpc with the flag -prof-gen:srcpos in order to perform a code coverage analysis. This works fine for some parts of my code, but I have problems in a few libraries.

I get the error

```
    undefined reference to std::string::_S_compare(unsigned long, unsigned long)
```

I link againt the /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13.

Unfortunately, I am unable to identify the difference between code that can be compiled and code that cant. One lib that does not compile is statically build and linked.

Best regards, Georg

Comment: Does it work if you don't use `-prof-gen:srcpos`?  Maybe you're compiling with headers that don't match the library you're linking against?  Are you ignoring any compiler warnings?

Comment: Yes it works if I don't compile with the -prof-gen option. Then the symbol _S_compare is not referenced in the object file, but if I turn on code coverage it is referenced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the intel compiler version 15.0.3 20150407 and 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17).

After updating to gcc 4.8.2 20140120 it is working fine. In the old gcc version the required function is not provided.

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled with the same error.  Below is a fix to be able to compile the same code on RHEL5 and RHEL6 and not get the error you listed when generating Intel coverage reports.  Just place this snippet in the `.cpp` file that the compiler complains is missing the symbol.

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// NOTE: The block below is ONLY needed for building with the
//       Intel code-coverage flags turned on. For some reason,
//       this comes up as an un-resolved symbol. So, for CODE
//       COVERAGE BUILDS ONLY, this symbol is defined here.

#if defined __INTEL_CODE_COVERAGE__ && defined __GLIBC__

// Specify that 2.6 is required because we know that 2.5 does NOT need this.
// The macro tests for >=. Will need to tune this if other glibc versions are in use.
// We have RHEL5 using 2.5, RHEL6 using 2.12.

#if __GLIBC_PREREQ(2,6) 

namespace std {
    template int string::_S_compare(size_type, size_type);
}

#endif /* glibc version >= 2.6 */

#endif /* intel code coverage and using glibc */

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```